# Enableing HTML5 in webkit browser

Tags: c#, html, webkit, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a program in C# using the webkit browser and sites that use HTML5 do no render properly as HTML5 is not enabled. I was wondering if HTLM5 was supported and if so how do I enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something like Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/). You could 'test' for functionality and fallback/exclude features as needed.